# how to choose the colours for different states for android components(ie pressed.selected focused..etc)

Tags: color, color-theory, interface-design, user-experience

i am working with android project i choosen flat design for app...i got struggle on choosing the colours for pressed state..as per my design background is white..normal button is red...now the problem start for me..is there any guidelines is there for choosing colours..or if any body knows kindly share..thanks in advance[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are guidelines by Google, you can find them here: https://developer.android.com/design/index.html

Comment: Any specific reason for the downvote?

Comment: I've up-voted as I find this a perfectly reasonable answer for Rachuru's problem